# Request in newman

Tags: node.js, newman

.on('request') is not getting executed in newman. Is there anything to be installed to run newman?. Here is my code.

```
const newman = require('newman');
const fs = require('fs');
newman.run({
collection: require('./Collection.json'),
reporters: 'cli'
}).on('request',(error,data) => {
    console.log("Coming")
    if(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(data)
});

fs.writeFile(`foo.txt`, 'bar', function (error) {
if (error) { 
    console.error(error); 
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed "newman"? if not, please execute "npm install -g newman" or "npm install newman" locally.
ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#using-newman-as-a-library